# (Angular2) Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined for toastr

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, toastr

I'm trying to use toastr in angularjs 2 as a service which will be injected in my component as mentioned below. When the handleEvent function is called i'm receiving "Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined". Any suggestions and/or explanation for the error is much appreciated.

app.moudle.ts has imported ToastrService and ToastrService has been added in providers.

```
//events/events-list.components.ts

import { ToastrService } from '../common/toastr.service';
@Component ({
    selector: 'event-list',
    template: `
    <div>
        <h1> Upcoming Angular 2 Event </h1>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div *ngFor="let event_data of all_data" class="col-md-5">
                <event-thumbnail (click)="handleEvent(event_data.name)" [event]="event_data"></event-thumbnail>
    </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    `
})

export class EventListComponent implements OnInit {
  all_data:any[]
  constructor(private eventService : EventService , private toastr : ToastrService ){
    //moved code from here to ngOnInit 
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.all_data = this.eventService.getEvents();
  }

  handleEvent(eventName) {
    console.log("hey here  "+eventName);
    this.toastr.success(eventName);
  }
}
```

**Error:**
[ This error is thrown after the console.log output ]

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./EventListComponent class EventListComponent -
>   inline template:6:16 caused by: Cannot read property 'extend' of
>   undefined. 
>               ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
>              TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
>       at m (toastr.js:411)
>       at Object.s [as success] (toastr.js:85)
>       at ToastrService.success (toastr.service.ts:12)

Comment: What is ToastrService?

Comment: It's like we are coding the same thing - I was just about to ask that :D

Comment: Did you include JQuery?

Comment: Embarrassingly, no. I included both in 'scripts' section of angular-cli and it works, thank you!

Is there a better way?

Comment: @kemsky : yes jquery has been included and i don't have any dependency exception upon loading the app.

Comment: @RomanC  I would guess that ToastrService is a wrapper around the Toastr library. And again another guess but Mad-D was watching the same Pluralsight Angular course that I'm watching now.

Comment: @DanielHollinrake I don't know how it's integrated into the code. But if you use the typescript it's provided by the `import` directive. For example see how to import services [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47851377/573032).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Add this 
 `script src="node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.js"`

After this
 `script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Reason :  `toastr.js` uses `jQuery`, so `jQuery` should get loaded before `toastr.js`

Comment: For Angular v12.x.x, you must add it to _scripts_  section inside **angular.json** file

Answer (score 3):

Also bootstrap.min.css should bet loaded before toastr.min.js.

Environments: Angular 7 and bootstrap 4.

Below is my part of angular.json, and it is working.

```
   "styles": [
      "node_modules/ngf-bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.css",
      "node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.css",
      "src/styles.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
      "node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.js"
    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

This did the trick for me:

```
"scripts": [ 
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
]
```

In that exact order inside the `angular.json` file under the scripts section.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to import jquery before using toastr. Its a requirement for toastr.

Answer (score 0):

1. open terminal -> `npm install jquery --save`
2. Go to the `angular.json` file add the following:

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.js"
]
```