# How to insert a Angular service into a function in a Module file outside the class?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some function in my `app.module.ts` file after Module class declaration

```
export function exportTranslateStaticLoader(http: HttpClient, config: RuntimeConfigLoaderService, transferState: TransferState, cookie: CookieService) {
  let apiUrl;
  if (environment.browser.symphonyApiUrl) {
    apiUrl = environment.browser.symphonyApiUrl;
  } else {
    const protocol = window.location.protocol;
    const host = window.location.host;
    apiUrl = `${protocol}//api.${host}`;
  }
  const link = environment.remoteTranslate ? `${apiUrl}/cms/locale/` : '/assets/i18n/';
  return new TranslateBrowserLoader(link, '.json', transferState, http, cookie);
}
```

and use them in imports section

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: exportTranslateStaticLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient, TransferState, CookieService]
      }
    }),
```

I'm need use some service (`RuntimeConfigLoaderService`)  in this function, how do it ?

Answer (score 0):

*You can use an intermediate service `@Injectable` to make sure that `HttpClient` and other are provided as a singleton ,

 then `TranslateBrowserLoader` should be a return type of a function in this  `@Injectable`*.

```html
@Injectable()
export class TranslateLoader {

  constructor(
      private http: HttpClient,
      private config: RuntimeConfigLoaderService,
      private transferState: TransferState,
      private cookie: CookieService
       ) {}

// import exportTranslateStaticLoader

getTranslateStaticLoader() : TranslateBrowserLoader {
   return exportTranslateStaticLoader(
      this.http,
      this.config,
      this.transferState,
      this.cookie
     )
 }
```

Comment: how to call getTranslateStaticLoader method in app.module.file ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851312/when-import-services-should-i-import-them-in-imports-array-or-providers-array